# How to set focus on last line of WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, focus, richtextbox

I am dynamically adding text in a `RichTextBox`.

How can I set `Focus` on the last line so the user can see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will move the caret to the last line:

```
richTextBox.CaretPosition = richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd;
```

But it will not scroll the `richTextBox` to make the caret visible.  To accomplish that you also have to call `ScrollToEnd()`:

```
richTextBox.CaretPosition = richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd;
richTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
```